# Controller method not found. error in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, controller, laravel-5

My controller file looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Artist;
use App\Song;
use App\Album;

class WebsiteController extends Controller
{


    public function getIndex(){

        return redirect('/');

    }

    public function getHome(){

        $featuredArtist='';
        $featuredAlbum='';
        $featuredSong='';

        return view('website.welcome')->with(array('featuredArtist'=>$featuredArtist,'featuredSong'=>$featuredSong,'featuredAlbum'=>$featuredAlbum));

    }


    public function get_listartist(){

    $artistList = Artist::select('id','artist_name', 'artist_title','artist_image')->get();
    //dd($artistList);
    return view('website.listartist')->with(array('artistList'=>$artistList));
    //skljhkhkl
}

    public function getDonate(){

        return view('website.donate');
    }

    public function getContact(){

        return view('website.contact');
    }
}
```

And My Route.php looks like this

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'WebsiteController@getHome');
Route::controller('site', 'WebsiteController');
```

Most of the links are working other than

www.domain.com/site/listartist

I am getting error as

> NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php line 9361: Controller method not
>   found..

Any Idea I checked everything it looks fine

[**URLOFTheWebSite**](http://mad.ideleads.com/site/listartist)

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any function with the name `listartist` in you `Controller`?

Comment: @BasheerAhmed in laravel if its a get method it resolves to this function `getListartist()` The same code works fine in the localhost btw

Comment: Oops I just forget that but non of the url is working. url `http://mad.ideleads.com/site/home`
`Class 'App\Http\Controllers\BaseController' not found`

Comment: @BasheerAhmed please check now , I was trying to apply some change it didn't work out , Now its not working only for few of the urls rest is working fine

Comment: try `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: last three methods aren't working either `donate, contact or listartist`...

Comment: @BasheerAhmed yes thats what I do not understand that , And I already run `Cache:clear`

Comment: hope my answer help you..!

Answer (score 0):

Try `snake-case` name for the methods instead. I don't know why but `camel-case` is not working for methods consist of two words.

```
public function get_some_name() {};  // www.example.com/anything/some-name
public function get_somename() {};  // www.example.com/anything/somename
//it doesn't seem to work with camel-case e.x  getSomename(); www.example.com/anything/somename
public function get_version() {}; //It will also work with camel-case
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am getting confused Bhai, Are you saying I should change the URL from `listartist` to `list_artist` and then in my controller i should change the function to `get_list_artist()`??

Comment: the function name or the url ??

Comment: just change function name

Comment: tried it bro not working for me this is so weird the website works totally fine on the localhost , But when I load it on the VPS its acting like this

Comment: @Vikram update you controller code above so I could check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110516/discussion-between-vikram-and-basheer-ahmed).

Answer (score 0):

Even this is old, it still can help new visitors. I got the same error and found it was my controller path given in web.php wrong.

Ex: 
Instead of :
Route::get('/', 'WebsiteController@getHome');

give
Route::get('/', 'admin\WebsiteController@getHome');